# jquery.js:8526 GET /siteurl/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, http-status-code-404

I am trying to set URL in ajax script for adding a new pizza on my page but I cannot address it.

My website is hosted at `localhost/wwwPizza/`.

On first try `$.ajax({ url: "wwwPizza/objednat.php" })` gets a wrong addresation because there is 2 `WwwPizza` folders. On the second try `$.ajax({ url: "/objednat.php" })`, when I delete `WwwPizza`, there is no `WwwPizza` addresation...

My folders:

[image]

Comment: You're essentially asking how to link from a file to another file in the same folder. And you managed to place the leading slash at exactly the wrong version. Use either `/wwwPizza/objednat.php` or just `objednat.php`

Comment: When i use adress: /wwwPizza/objednat.php it shows me: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <!DOCTYPE html>

When i use just 'objednat.php' it shows me the same

Comment: That's a different problem. Do `console.log(html);`, what does it say?

Comment: Thanks for help, but my friend already helped me with it..  My code now: https://imgur.com/a/fuZkoyo